# Find maximum and minimum value of a given vector x and return the values as a vector

Tags: r

Condition given is to write this using a function-

Necessary code that has to be present is

```
x <- c(10,20,30,40,50,20,25,35)
my_function <- function(x) {
    enter code here
}
```

I tried writing the below mentioned code but its showing as error. Please revert back how to get the desired output as a vector

Comment: You can use `range(x)`.

Comment: If you need to write your own function for homework purposes you can simply do: `my_function <- function(x) c(min(x), max(x))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `range()`:

```r
x <- c(10,20,30,40,50,20,25,35)
range(x)
#> [1] 10 50
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>